# Can't read $_POST data when a javascript function is called

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have listed a table with data from MySQL and actions to EDIT or DELETE the row.

[image]

Here's the code for the image above:

```
<table border="1" class="gridtable">
               <th>Client Name</th>
               <th>Category</th>
               <th>Address</th>
               <th>City</th>
               <th>Contact Person</th>
               <th>Contact Details</th>
               <th>Sales Person</th>
               <th colspan="2"></th>
               <?php
                $a=mysql_query("SELECT `clients`.`client-no`, `clients`.`client-name`, `clients`.`client-category`, `clients`.`client-address`, `clients`.`client-city`, `clients`.`client-contact-person`, `clients`.`client-contact-details`, `sales`.`firstname`, `sales`.`lastname` 
                                FROM `clients`
                                INNER JOIN `sales`
                                ON `clients`.`sales-id`=`sales`.`sales-id`") or die(mysql_error());
                if(mysql_num_rows($a)>0)
                {
                    while($b=mysql_fetch_array($a))
                    {
                        echo"<tr><td>".$b['client-name']."</td><td>".$b['client-category']."</td><td>".$b['client-address']."</td><td>".$b['client-city']."</td><td>".$b['client-contact-person']."</td><td>".$b['client-contact-details']."</td><td>".$b['firstname'].' '.$b['lastname']."</td>"; ?>
                        <td>
                        <form action="#" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="edit_client" value="<?php echo $b['client-no']; ?>" />
                        <input type="image" name="edit_client" value="<?php echo $b['client-no']; ?>" src="images/edit.png" onclick="javascript:editPopup()" title="Edit"/>

                        </form>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <form action="../deletefunction.php" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="delete_client" value="<?php echo $b['client-no']; ?>" />
                        <input type="image" name="delete_client" value="<?php echo $b['client-no']; ?>" src="images/delete.png" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?')" title="Delete"/>

                        </form>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ?>
                    <tr><td colspan="6" style="text-align:center; color:#FF0000; font-size:16px;">*No Data Available!*</td></tr>
                    <?php
                }

               ?>
               </table>
              <a href="javascript:addClient()" id="addclient"><img src="images/add.png" class="addicon" style=" display:inline;" /></a>
```

The DELETE function works fine but the EDIT isn't. Here's the code for the javascipt function the `<input type=image name=edit_client />` is calling on its `onclick`:

```
function editPopup()
{
    var url = "../editfunction.php";
    var width = 700;
    var height = 600;
    var left = parseInt((screen.availWidth/2) - (width/2));
    var top = parseInt((screen.availHeight/2) - (height/2));
    var windowFeatures = "width=" + width + ",height=" + height +   
        ",status,resizable,left=" + left + ",top=" + top + 
        "screenX=" + left + ",screenY=" + top + ",scrollbars=yes";

    window.open(url, "subWind", windowFeatures, "POS");
}
```

Basically, what it does is to popup the `editfunction.php` in a new window in the center of a monitor. The page should display the UPDATE page with the data coming from the `$_POST[edit_client]`. But it seems like the `editfunction.php` can't read the data from the first page since it errors `Notice: Undefined index: edit_client in C:\xampp\htdocs\isys\editfunction.php on line 12
-yeah`. Here's its code:

```
<?php

require("dbconnect.php");
echo $_POST['edit_client']."-yeah";

//edit client
if(isset($_POST['edit_client']) && !empty($_POST['edit_client'])) 
{
  echo $_POST['edit_client']."-yeah";
  //do the update here
}

?>
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I make this work? Thanks.

PS: Please don't mind the usage of `mysql_` and stay focus on the question itself.

Comment: All I can see is that you have `<form action="../deletefunction.php" method="post">` for your DELETE, yet `<form action="#" method="post">` for your EDIT function. Shouldn't that be `<form action="../editfunction.php" method="post">`? Other than that, I'm at a loss.

Comment: Yeah I tried that. But that would display the `editfunction.php` on the same window. I need the edit page on a popup window.

Comment: I thought you said/wrote that the DELETE function worked, therefore I assumed doing something similar would work.

Comment: The DELETE function does it differently because it doesn't need to popup in a new window.

Comment: In other words, the SQL deletion query works, it just won't pop up, correct?

Comment: By the way, you should really consider reading about coding standards in PHP. This is what most programmers would call the 'spaghetti code' that PHP is famous for. HTML intermingled with PHP intermingled with SQL, all using deprecated functions and no separation of concerns.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I don't need to popup the DELETE function. I just need to call the deletefunction page for it to work. My main problem is on the EDIT  function. Don't mind the DELETE function.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist, could you provide a link for what you mentioned?

Comment: Fair enough. I suppose the [PEAR Coding Standards](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php) are as close to a standard as you could get with PHP. A subset of the [Wordpress Coding Standards](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards) apply to general PHP, and they are quite good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow found a workaround on how to achieve what I want using the `onsubmit` function of the `<form>`:

`<form action="../editfunction.php" method="post" target="DoSubmit" onsubmit="DoSubmit = window.open('about:blank', 'DoSubmit', windowFeatures, 'POS');">`

And I placed this code on the head of the `index` for the popup window:

```
    var width = 700;
    var height = 600;
    var left = parseInt((screen.availWidth/2) - (width/2));
    var top = parseInt((screen.availHeight/2) - (height/2));
    var windowFeatures = "width=" + width + ",height=" + height +   
        ",status,resizable,left=" + left + ",top=" + top + 
        "screenX=" + left + ",screenY=" + top + ",scrollbars=yes";
```

Thank you all for your help. I greatly appreciated it! :)

Answer (score 0):

the form is not submitted. you're launching the event but you don't submit the form. you should do as the delete button and have the image button submit the form to the editfunction.php page.

Comment: But I need to do the onclick because I want to open the `editfunction.php` in a new window at the center of the monitor.

Comment: you should instead use the onsubmit event on the form and then return false to prevent the page from changing

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand better what you are trying to do now, and maybe a `GET` request isn't so bad here. Just make sure you `POST` when you submit from edit client.

You need to structure the URL you pass to `window.open` like so:

```
editfunction.php?edit_client=1
```

Where 1 is the numeric id of your client. This can be easily supplied by JavaScript in the same way you are supplying the URL.

```
var url = "../editfunction.php?edit_client="+client_id;
```

If you need to supply more than one variable, separate them with ampersands:

```
editfunction.php?edit_client=1&second_var=2
```

All of these will later be accessible under the `$_GET` superglobal. Just change `$_POST['edit_client']` to `$_GET['edit_client']` in your PHP to catch the change.

Original answer intact below

---

Your PHP script is configured to accept a `POST` request.

```
$_POST['edit_client']
```

You call this variable before testing for its existence so you get undefined index ('edit_client') because it's not in the $_POST array.

It's not in the POST array because nowhere in your code do you POST any data to the server. You use `window.open` but that will send a GET request, and you won't be sending along any data unless you encode it in the URL (`editfunction.php?arg1=val1&arg2=val2`). If you want to POST data, you need to use AJAX. JQuery has a pretty simple [AJAX library](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) if you want to use it.

Note that the use of AJAX does not preclude the use of a popup. For example, you could fetch the data from a PHP script as HTML, and render that in the popup window using JavaScript.

Comment: You mean I can make it work if I encode the data on the URL? Can you make an example on how to do this?

Comment: The `edit_client` would be the `client-id` to be use to display all the client's data.

Comment: Updated answer with a GET example.